# Corona SDK - TextField Gets Left On Screen

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a working textfield in corona...I instantiated it using:

```
local nameTextField = native.newTextField (centerX, roundedRect.y + roundedRect.height*1.7, 300, 80)

nameTextField:addEventListener( "userInput", textListener )
```

I then made sure to add this to the scene's self.view in the create method:

```
function scene:create( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    sceneGroup:insert(nameTextField)
end
```

The whole scene is shown using a `showoverlay` method.

```
composer.showOverlay( "renameoverlay", options )
```

When I hide the scene using `hide overlay`:

```
composer.hideOverlay( "fade", 400 )
```

Even after hiding the whole scene using the above code, the nameTextField still gets left on the screen.
This doesn't happen inside my other scenes.

What could be causing this????
How do I solve this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, native.newTextField()'s can be added to display.newGroup()'s. The will move with groups, but they still sit on top of the display hierarchy. Scene's that use fade or crossFade can't hide the text fields because they are not being moved.

Since it looks like your overlay is using "fade", you will need to hide the text fields when you call showOverlay and show them when you're done with the overlay.

Scope matters too. I can't tell what part of your code you're creating the new text field, but it has to be visible to any place you are referencing it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that native objects can't be added to dispaly groups , you need to remove the native object when you hide the scene, try this:

add scene:hide(event)

```
function scene:hide(event)

   if nameTextField then
    nameTextField :removeSelf()
    nameTextField = nil
   end
end

scene:addEventListener("hide", scene)
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure it is because of access issue for the local variable.

Change this

```
local nameTextField = native.newTextField (centerX, roundedRect.y + roundedRect.height*1.7, 300, 80)
```

to this

```
nameTextField = native.newTextField (centerX, roundedRect.y + roundedRect.height*1.7, 300, 80)
```

or this

```
function scene:create( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    sceneGroup:insert(nameTextField)
end
```

to this

```
function scene:create( event )
    sceneGroup = self.view
    sceneGroup:insert(nameTextField)
end
```